# Einstein Reply Recommendations not visible in setup

Tags: einstein, chat, einstein-chatbot, summer20, einstein-next-best-action

As per Summer'20 Release notes **Help Chat Agents Respond Faster with Einstein Reply Recommendations is generally available**.

But I don't see 'Reply Recommendations' in setup, both in Lightning and classic.

Is this future generally available? or does it require any extra setup to get this option?

Answer (score 1):

After reading the documentation clearly, I have realized that the feature is available in **Enterprise, Performance and Unlimited** editions only. Also, it requires **Service Cloud Einstein add-on license**.

In my case, the org is Unlimited edition but the license was not available and that is why the option is not visible in setup.

​​​​​​​
I also have verified in both Developer edition and Trailhead Playgrounds, but this option is not available.​​​​​​​